# Regex(es) to extract the URL from different strings

Tags: regex, autohotkey

What regex(es) will extract the URL from strings with these patterns?

```
https://xxx##.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=[encoded URL to extract]&data=[more detritus]
https://example.com/link/?url=[encoded URL to extract]%3Fl%3Den-us
https://example.com/link/?url=[encoded URL to extract]
```

The first part will be `\?url=`; I am less certain about what comes next, and whether I need to use separate regexes for each pattern. Taking the first pattern,

```
https://xxx##.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F&data=[more detritus]
```

I would want to extract `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F` (to decode with an existing function.)

Comment: Can you add an example for the input and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=url=)[^&\s]+%2[fF](?:[^&\s%]*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yt4lYs/1).

Comment: Thank you; this works for the first pattern; can it be adapted for the other two, or would a separate regex be a better approach?

Comment: I am only interested in the `url` parameter; the trouble is discarding the appended `l` parameter in the second pattern.

Comment: @user2319146 I think I understood what you have said if you mean this part `[encoded URL to extract]%3Fl%3Den-us` this is because there are spaces in the sentence `[encoded URL to extract]` and  you previously mentioned that the `url` value is URL-encoded which means it will contain no spaces at the value, I believe if you replace the pseudo value `[]encoded URL to extract` with a real URL-encoded value such as `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F` the regex pattern will work fine.

Comment: `%3Fl%3Den-us` is still appended to the `url` parameter.

Comment: @user2319146 I know that but the `url` parameter value in this case is not a valid URL-encoded value because of the first part `[encoded URL to extract]`

Comment: @user2319146 If the value of the `url` parameter is URL-encoded it should be like `%5Bencoded%20URL%20to%20extract%5D` not `[encoded URL to extract]`

Comment: `[encoded URL to extract]` was just shorthand for `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F`.

Comment: @user2319146 remove the spaces and the pattern will match the `url` I mean replace it with `[encodedURLtoextract]`instead of `[encoded URL to extract]`.

Comment: @user2319146 I know it is a shorthand and because of that the pattern didn't match it, because it is not a valid URL-encoded value. put in a valid URL-encoded value and the pattern will match it.

Comment: If I substitute `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F` the result is `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F%3Fl%3Den-us`.

Comment: @user2319146 Yes and this value `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsubd%2Fdoc.aspx%2F%3Fl%3Den-us` is valid, if you mean the last part `  `%3Fl%3Den-us` if we decode the value it will be `?l=en-us` it is just a parameter related to the extracted URL.  and it means it is a valid URL-encoded value. Do you mean you want to get rid of the last part `%3Fl%3Den-us` ?

Comment: @user2319146 I updated the regex pattern can you check it again  and see the demo

Answer (score 4):

Autohotkey supports PCRE, in that case you can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far:

```
https?:\/\/[^\s?]+\?url=\K[^\s&]+
```

**Explanation**

- `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol with optional `s`
- `[^\s?]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `?`
- `\?url=` Match `?url=`
- `\K` Clear the current match buffer (forget what is matched so far)
- `[^\s&]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `&`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FTdLv3/1).

Comment: Thank you; this works for the first pattern, but does not discard `%3Fl%3Den-us` in the second pattern.

Comment: @user2319146 If you want to end the match with %2f `https?:\/\/[^\s?]+\?url=\K[^\s&]+%2[fF]` See https://regex101.com/r/l19WJF/1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the URL parameters are separated correctly with ampersands (&), then this should work, I think: `url=(.+?)(&|$)`

Comment: Thank you; this works for the first pattern, but adds `url=` at the start and `&` at the end.

Comment: @user2319146 This should, theoretically, work for any of the patterns. As for the `url=` at the start and `&` at the end, these are part of the full match, but they should not be included in the capture group. In AutoHotKey, I believe capture groups are held in a pseudo array called OutputVar. The URL part you're looking for will be in that array.